# List of files in folder

Tags: list, function, ftp, filemaker

I am trying to find a function (or write one) that allows me to see a list of files inside a particular location, the Base Elements function 'BE_FileListFolder' does a good job of this, but I can only get this to work on the local network, for example I can see whats in the My Documents folder without any issues.

What I am trying to achieve is the same, but the directory I would like to see in is an FTP location. Can anyone help or advise me on the best approach for this?

TLDR; Would like to be able to see a list of files in FM of an FTP location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using the BaseElements plugin, you can use the BE_HTTP_GET function to get a FTP file listing.

```
BE_Curl_Set_Option ( "CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY" ; 1 )

BE_HTTP_GET ( "sftp://server/path/" ; "" ; <user_name> ; <password> )
```

Fetched from [BaseElements](https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204700658-BE-HTTP-GET) documentation.

EDIT: If you are using FileMaker 16 or newer, you may also use the built-in function Insert from URL which now supports FTP directory listing through cURL options.

Comment: Amazing, this does exactly what I was hoping for. Thankyou Andreas.